# Persisting EventType with Serilog

Tags: serilog

I'm having trouble getting the EventType feature working in Serilog, as blogged about [here](https://nblumhardt.com/2015/10/assigning-event-types-to-serilog-events/).

I am using the following Nuget packages:

- Serilog 2.8
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.0.1
- Serilog.Sinks.File 4.0.0
- Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.2

First up, I created an *EventTypeEnricher*:

```
public class EventTypeEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
        var hash = crypto.Compute(logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text);
        var numericHash = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hash), 0);
        var eventId = propertyFactory.CreateProperty("EventType", numericHash);
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(eventId);
    }
}
```

This seems to work (more on that later, but at the end of that method, a property is added with an *EventType* value in the *EventId* variable can be observed while debugging).

I created an extension method which adds this enricher:

```
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithEventType(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        if (enrichmentConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrichmentConfiguration));
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With<EventTypeEnricher>();
    }
```

I then use that when I configure the Logger:

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithEventType()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

I go to write the error like this:

```
logger.Write(LogEventLevel.Error,
    contextFeature.Error,
    MessageTemplates.LogEntryDetailMessageTemplate,
    new LogEntryDetail
    {
        Exception = contextFeature.Error,
        Message = "Bad Stuff",
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
        MessageTemplate = MessageTemplates.LogEntryDetailMessageTemplate,
        Severity = LogEventLevel.Error
    });
```

My Serilog appsettings section is as follows:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "MyAssembly" ],
    "Enrich": [ "EventTypeEnricher" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs//Errorlog.log",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1073741824,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 30,
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
      },
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ADb;User Id=Serilog;Password=securepwd;",
          "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
          "period": 30,
          "columnOptionsSection": {
            "disableTriggers": true,
            "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
            "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
            "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
            "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
            "additionalColumns": [
              {
                "ColumnName": "EventType",
                "DataType": "int",
                "AllowNull": true
              }
            ],
            "id": { "nonClusteredIndex": true },
            "level": {
              "columnName": "Level",
              "storeAsEnum": false
            },
            "timeStamp": {
              "columnName": "Timestamp",
              "convertToUtc": true
            },
            "logEvent": {
              "excludeAdditionalProperties": true,
              "excludeStandardColumns": true
            },
            "message": { "columnName": "Message" },
            "exception": { "columnName": "Exception" },
            "messageTemplate": { "columnName": "MessageTemplate" }
          }
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
      }
    ]
  }
```

My database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ErrorLogs](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [int] NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageTemplate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Level] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Properties] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LogEvent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ErrorLogs] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
```

The EventType column in the database is always null, despite the code in the custom enricher running.

It is not written to the file sink either.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or missing?

Cheers

Comment: Is it a .net core application?

Comment: @wael it is, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer version `5.1.3` fixed the issue as current stable version `5.1.2` not reading all `columnOptionsSection` section

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer -Version 5.1.3
```

And below updated configuration will fix your issue as you miss table mapping for `EventType` field

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "MyAssembly" ],
  "Enrich": [ "WithEventType" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "Logs//Errorlog.log",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1073741824,
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 30,
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
      },
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Verbose"
    },
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ADb;User Id=Serilog;Password=securepwd;",
        "tableName": "ErrorLogs",
        "autoCreateSqlTable": false,
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "disableTriggers": true,
          "clusteredColumnstoreIndex": false,
          "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
          "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent" ],
          "additionalColumns": [
            {
              "ColumnName": "EventType",
              "DataType": "int",
              "AllowNull": true
            }
          ],
          "id": {
            "columnName": "Id",
            "nonClusteredIndex": true
          },
          "eventType": {
            "columnName": "EventType"
          },
          "message": {
            "columnName": "Message"
          },
          "messageTemplate": {
            "columnName": "MessageTemplate"
          },
          "level": {
            "columnName": "Level",
            "storeAsEnum": false
          },
          "timeStamp": {
            "columnName": "TimeStamp",
            "convertToUtc": true
          },
          "exception": {
            "columnName": "Exception"
          },
          "properties": {
            "columnName": "Properties"
          },
          "logEvent": {
            "columnName": "LogEvent"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And Logger configuration as below

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I upgraded and gave it a shot, but lost all logging altogether. I've had to downgrade. At least with the stable release, in my application, it will log everything except the EventType. Might have to log a GIT ticket with the project author.

Comment: @onefootswill did you update your appsetting as in my answer? and make sure to remove old table first

Comment: I did, yes. It did not create the table unfortunately.

Comment: @onefootswill use `Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));` at program startup to enable serilog debug to check what is wrong

Comment: apologies. I did not add the Create Table permission to the Serilog user because in my original config, I was not autocreating the table. Your changed did work and the EventTypeId is populating. It would be preferable for me to create the table manually, so I just need to figure out how to get that json config right to work with an existing table. Not sure if that is yet done in the pre-release.

Comment: @onefootswill check updated answer for  creating table manually